# Emacs Ensime-sbt not responding to enter after I try to use RUN command

Tags: scala, emacs, ensime

I am using emacs to program in scala, now I installed ensime to be able to run SBT directly from emacs.

I use C-c-C-v-s to launch a buffer for ensime-sbt.

but when I type the run and hit enter nothing happens, how to make sbt run run ?

It's working find in command line

I am using Emacs 23 and Ensime in windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding "-Djline.WindowsTerminal.directConsole=false" to your sbt startup command. This fixed the problem for me.

From here: http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/IntegrationSupport